# imacros loop forward in csv to dowload file

Tags: loops, csv, imacros

brand new to coding and imacros.

I'm having trouble using LOOP to move forward in a CSV file (address.csv) in iMacros. I have the following simple CSV: Column A is URL and Column B is Filename.

I would like to:

1. go to URL specified in Column A, Row 2 (Row 1 is header)
2. Download the image specified in Column B, Row 2.
3. Go to the next row (Row 3) download the image and continue down the list (LOOP)

Using the following code, I'm able to get the first image in row 2 but can't move forward to row 3, 4, 5 to get the rest of the files. Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I tried to hack together using the demos and a macro i recorded:

```
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074
'Uses a Windows script to submit several datasets to a website, e. g. for filling an online database
TAB T=1     
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS  
' Specify input file (if !COL variables are used, IIM automatically assume a CSV format of the input file
'CSV = Comma Separated Values in each line of the file
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
'Start at line 2 to skip the header in the file
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !LOOP 2
'Increase the current position in the file with each loop 
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
VERSION BUILD=8340723 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:/download-photo/{{!COL2}} ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>hi-res<SP>photo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*Back*
```

Comment: Are you playing this macro in loop mode (with the 'Play (Loop)' button)?

Comment: did you run as loop? did you get an error? does the script run through the loops and do nothing or stop?
try in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer; here's the macro

```
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:/download-photo/{{!COL2}} ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>hi-res<SP>photo
WAIT SECONDS=2
```